# How to deal with huge database in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am working with on project where they deal huge data. In each table 100k or more data are available. Now I need to run sql update query but I don't works.

How can I solve this problem ? Query runs successfully on my localhost with few data. But On server it does not work

Please help me.

```
UPDATE buzz_business_view b, daily_deals d
SET d.business_id = b.`Business ID`
WHERE d.phone = b.phone
```

Thanks

Comment: You should post your query and a little more information about your table

Comment: Query is running successfully on localhost. Though I added in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the columns you are joining are indexed.

Use a where constraint to select a few rows at a time. Do not attempt to update the entire table in one shot.

Logically divide your table into multiple sections based on the table's primary key(s) and update one section at a time.

Answer (score 0):

For optimum performance, you're going to want suitable indexes available for the JOIN predicate.

```
CREATE INDEX ... ON buzz_business_view (phone,`Business ID`) ;

CREATE INDEX ... ON daily_deals (phone) ;
```

---

When you say that the UPDATE statement "does not work", does the statement throw an error, does it just seem to hang, or is the statement completing successfully but the results are not as you expect.